# How to retrieve a record with a binary id

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

We have a table in SQL Server.  Some genius made the identify field the type binary(8).  Whatever anyone else may say, that's a bad idea.  I've been trying for over an hour to get a record out of the table in Entity Framework using Linq.  I can do it in SQL Management Studio using the criteria "WHERE Contact_Id = 53147", but in EF the field is declared as type byte[] so it won't take an int parameter.  I found a way to convert my int to byte[], but it still can't find the record.  How can I construct a query in Linq that will retrieve this simple record?

Comment: When you run the query in which you've converted the int to a byte array, can you profile the query to see what's actually being run? Maybe that will provide some insight (e.g. maybe you put the bytes in the array in the wrong order).

Comment: I saw that insane tidbit in the code to convert int to byte[].  So I tried it with and without reversal.  It does not return a match either way.  As far as SQL Profiler, I never use that tool and if I did I probably wouldn't know what to do with the results.

Comment: Ah. As for profiler, I'd be curious to see what ID is actually being searched for from your code. You may be able to detect a pattern. Alternatively, you can use stored procedures with EF. In this case, it may be worth it.